# Prevent JavaFx Scene from gaining focus - Onscreen Keyboard

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to build an onscreen keyboard in javafx. The only issue I am having is that when you select the javafx scene or click a button on the window, the focus is then redirected to the javafx scene and the button click doesn't actually type a letter on a browser, text document, etc.

Here is my code for the button click. I'm using the robot class.

```
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws AWTException {

    Robot a = new Robot();
    a.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);//testing keypress of "Y".

}
```

I've seen in Swing how you can set a focus property to false, but I'm set on using JavaFx. I've seen quite a few people attempt this same question, but no one has a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is currently no way to achieve this purely with JavaFx.

Here is [an example](https://gist.github.com/flasheater/c9698469507c709d15825c932eceae4f) how you could achieve it by wrapping your JavaFx-App in a Swing-App. An architectural monstrosity ;).

Alternatively, I could imagine that using a native layer like JNI/JNA is possible in this scenario.

However, in this case I would question if Java is technically the right tool for the job. One might argue, that an OSK is by definition tightly coupled to the OS and as such more native toolkits are in order. This of course depends on the scope of your project. As a side project this might be fine, but as a product not.